# 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, geodjango

So I am currently new to Django and developing a GeoDjango application where I need users to be able to upload Shapefiles and Point Features into the database.
I am currently using **PostgreSQL** as my database.

Running:
`python manage.py makemigrations` is not a problem at all. The problems comes when I try to migrate using:
`python manage.py migrate`

I get the **'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type** Error.

My models.py file likes like this

```
class Beacon(models.Model):
    land_id = models.OneToOneField(Land, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()
    beacons = models.MultiPointField()
```

and also the Database configuration part in my settings.py file looks like so,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'LIMS',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '<my_password_is_here>',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

I have searched all over the internet but all solutions are not working out for me and seems like most of them are using PostGIS as the database.
If anyone could help regarding this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Below I've also included the full summary of the error

```
(LIMS) C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Desktop\Projects\Django\LIMS\LIMS>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, farm_inventory, sessions, users
Running migrations:
  Applying farm_inventory.0023_auto_20201225_1304...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Desktop\Projects\Django\LIMS\LIMS\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Desktop\Projects\Django\LIMS\LIMS\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 455, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 212, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 717, in db_parameters
    type_string = self.db_type(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Surveyor Jr\Envs\LIMS\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 105, in db_type
    return connection.ops.geo_db_type(self)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

Answer (score 15):

You are using wrong engine backend it should be as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#setting-up)

```
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

Also make sure you go through all rest of the steps and install required extensions and tools

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the db engine is not a geospatial one, you can find supported ones [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#module-django.contrib.gis.db.backends).

When using Postgres as database, you have to use the [PostGIS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatial-database) extension for Geodjango to work.

Follow the [steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/#geodjango-installation) in the official docs to enable Geodjango support